# Show that the set of strictly stationary, mean zero and finite variance stochastic processes is closed (or not)

Tags: pr.probability, gn.general-topology, stochastic-processes, limits-and-convergence

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of real-valued and strictly stationary processes with expectation zero and finite variance, i.e.:
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{P}:=\left\{ X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} \, :   \, X \hbox{ is strictly stationary, } \mathbb{E} X_t = 0 \hbox{ and } \mathbb{E}[X_t^2]< \infty, \, \forall\, t \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
\end{equation}
*Remark:* for any stochastic process $X$, we consider $Q$ the Law of a stochastic process according [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_(stochastic_processes)). We denote $X \sim Q$.

I'm trying to show whether or not $\mathcal{P}$ is closed according to the Mallows metric:

Let $X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} \sim P$ and $Y = (Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}\sim Q$ be two stochastic processes. In order to define the Mallows metric, for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$, let $\mathcal{M}_m$ be the random vectors $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ having marginals $P\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}$ and $Q\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}$, where $\pi_{1,...,m}(  (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} )= (X_{1},..., X_{m})$ . So:
$$d( (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}},(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}})= \sum_{m=1}^\infty d^{(m)}(P\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}, Q\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1})2^{-m}$$
where
$$d^{(m)}(P\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}, Q\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}) = \inf_{(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})\in \mathcal{M}_m}{(E||\tilde{X}-\tilde{Y}||^2)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}}.$$

Some hint?

Comment: What are the $t_j$'s?

Comment: They represent the indices of the marginal distributions of the stochastic process, more specifically, the distribution of an m-dimensional vector. Stationarity, I believe, is fundamental for the metric to be well defined.

Comment: I think I was confused such $t_j$'s indices. Now I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\newcommand{\PP}{\mathcal D}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$Your function $d$ is not a metric, for two reasons: (i) there may be many processes $(X_t)_{t\in\Z}$ with the same distribution $P$ and (ii) your function $d$ does not take into account the values of $X_t$ for negative $t\in\Z$. So, your $d$ is, not a metric, but a [pseudometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space), which does not allow one to identify limits uniquely.

We can fix these deficiencies as follows: Let $\PP$ denote the set of the distributions of the processes in $\mathcal P$.

Given $P$ and $Q$ in $\PP$, for any natural $m$ let
\begin{equation}
    P_m:=P\circ\pi_{-m,\dots,m}^{-1},\quad Q_m:=Q\circ\pi_{-m,\dots,m}^{-1},  
\end{equation}
where $\pi_{r,\dots,s}((x_t)_{t\in\Z}):=(x_r,\dots,x_s)$ for any given integers $r,s$ such that $r\le s$.
Let
\begin{equation}
    d(P,Q):=\sum_{m=1}^\infty d^{(m)}(P_m,Q_m)2^{-m}, 
\end{equation}
where $d^{(m)}$ is the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space) of order $2$.

We want then to show that  $\PP$ is closed with respect to the metric $d$.

Suppose now that we have a sequence $(P^{(n)})$ in $\PP$ such that $d(P^{(n)},Q)\to0$ (as $n\to\infty$) for some probability measure $Q$ (on the [cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_%CF%83-algebra)) over $\R^\Z$. Then for each natural $m$ we have $d^{(m)}(P^{(n)}_m,Q_m)\to0$. So, by the well-known [characterization of the convergence in the Wasserstein metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042947/characterization-of-wasserstein-convergence), $P^{(n)}_m\to Q_m$ weakly,
$\int_{\R^{\Z_m}} x_t^2\,Q_m(dx)=\lim_n\int_{\R^{\Z_m}} x_t^2\,P^{(n)}_m(dx)<\infty$, and
$\int_{\R^{\Z_m}} x_t\,Q_m(dx)=\lim_n\int_{\R^{\Z_m}} x_t\,P^{(n)}_m(dx)=\lim_n0=0$ for $t\in\Z_m:=\{-m,\dots,m\}$.

So, $\int_{\R^\Z} x_t\,Q(dx)=0$ and $\int_{\R^\Z} x_t^2\,Q(dx)<\infty$ for all $t\in\Z$, and
$P^{(n)}_{r,s}\to Q_{r,s}$ weakly for any given integers $r,s$ such that $r\le s$, where $P^{(n)}_{r,s}:=P^{(n)}\circ\pi_{r,\dots,s}^{-1}$ and $Q_{r,s}:=Q\circ\pi_{r,\dots,s}^{-1}$.

By the stationarity, $P^{(n)}_{r+1,s+1}=P^{(n)}_{r,s}$ for all suitable $r,s,n$. Letting now $n\to\infty$, we conclude that $Q_{r+1,s+1}=Q_{r,s}$, so that $Q$ is the distribution of a stationary process. Also, as we saw, $\int_{\R^\Z} x_t\,Q(dx)=0$ and $\int_{\R^\Z} x_t^2\,Q(dx)<\infty$ for all $t\in\Z$. So, $Q\in\PP$.

We conclude that $\PP$ is closed, as desired.

Comment: Some things are inconsistent. When you writte $d(P^{(n)},Q)$, it means that the $Q$ is in some general space where the metric $d$ is well defined. As the answer of Yuval Peres, we can take $\mathcal{P}_1$. In this case, it only remains to show that $Q$ is stationary. I couldn't understand why $P_m^{(n)}\to Q$ weakly. Maybe it's too obvious, but I can't see it. Could you explain? Thanks

Comment: @Fam : The weak convergence follows by the well-known characterization of the convergence in the Wasserstein metric. I have added a reference to this fact.

Comment: @fam : Also, you cannot actually take $\mathcal P_1$ for the set of probability measures $Q$ -- because $\mathcal P_1$ is a set of processes, not a set of measures. However, just as I wrote, $Q$ belongs to the set of all probability measures on the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Right, Iosif. What I said is that even $Q$ being a measure, it is not so straightforward and valid for you to use $d(P^{(n)},Q)$, as it is not clear that the metric is well defined in the Q's measures (on the cylindrical σ-algebra) over $R^\mathbb{Z}$. I believe it is necessary to restrict the metric to $\mathcal{P}_1$ (set of measures ). In this case, it is not necessary to show that the stochastic process has mean zer and finite variance.

Comment: @Fam : I can barely understand your latter comment. (i) You again are talking about "$\mathcal P_1$ (set of measures )". As I said, $\mathcal P_1$ is, not a set of measures, but a set of processes. Maybe, this is an issue of you expressing your thoughts. (ii) For any probability measures $P$ and $Q$ on the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra, the  probability measures $P_m$ and $Q_m$ are well defined, by the definition of the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra (as is done in my answer). So, $d(P,Q)$ **is** well defined.

Comment: Even with $P$ and $Q$ not having finite second moments?

Comment: @Fam : Perhaps, you are concerned that for some probability measures $P$ and $Q$ on the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra we may have $d(P,Q)=\infty$. But that is all right, because we **assume** that $d(P^{(n)},Q)\to0$ and hence $d(P^{(n)},Q)<\infty$ for all large enough $n$. So, the set $\mathcal D$ is closed, not only in the set of all probability measures $P$ on the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra with $\int x_t^2\,P(dx)<\infty$ for all $t$, but even in the set of (absolutely) all probability measures $P$ on the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra (even without finite second moments).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138622/discussion-between-fam-and-iosif-pinelis).

Comment: Sorry, I do not engage in such chat. I have answered all your questions, have I not? If you need more details, please let me know right here.

Comment: Right, I would like to leave one last question. About the law of a stochastic process (see Wikipedia link), as I quoted in my question, it would be defined on the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra) over $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ ? I ask this because the wiki article doesn't detail this. Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking that the law, as a measure of probability, is defined in the borelians of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: @Fam : (i) The cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra (say $\mathcal C$) is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which all the finite-dimensional projections are measurable. Therefore, $\mathcal C$ is the natural $\sigma$-algebra on which the distribution of a stationary process can be defined, thus resulting in the most general definition of such a distribution.

Comment: @Fam : (ii) The cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R^\mathbb Z$ corresponding to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R$ is the same as the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R^\mathbb Z$ corresponding to the product topology over $\mathbb R^\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  $\mathcal{P}$ is closed in the spaces
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{P}_1:=\left\{ X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} \, :   \,   \mathbb{E} X_t = 0 \hbox{ and } \mathbb{E}[X_t^2]< \infty, \, \forall\, t \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{P}_2:=\left\{ X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} \, :   \,      \mathbb{E}[X_t^2]< \infty, \, \forall\, t \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
\end{equation}
on which the Mallows metric is defined. Note that the metric is not defined on all processes, a second moment of the marginals is required to be finite. Also note that this is a metric on laws: two processes could be different mappings from the same probability space to the space of sequences, yet if they have the same law the Mallows distance between them is zero.

That $\mathcal{P}_1$ is closed in $\mathcal{P}_2$ is a standard consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, so we will focus on checking that $\mathcal{P}$ **is closed in** $\mathcal{P}_1$.

Suppose that the law $P$ of the process $X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is in the closure of $\mathcal{P}$ in $\mathcal{P}_1$. Let $S(P)$ be the law of the shifted process
$S(X) = (X_{t+1})_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} \sim S(P)$.

Observe that a process $X$ in $\mathcal{P}_1$  is strictly stationary iff $d(X,S(X))=0$.

Given $\epsilon>0$, we can find a process  $Y = (Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}\sim Q$ in $\mathcal{P}$ such that $d(X,Y)<\epsilon$. The definition of the Mallows metric then  yields that
$d(S(X),S(Y)) <2\epsilon$. Therefore,
$$d(X,S(X)) \le d(X,Y)+ d(Y,S(Y))+d(S(Y),S(X)) < \epsilon+0+2\epsilon=3\epsilon \,,$$
because $Y$ is strictly stationary.  Finally, since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary and the Mallows metric is indeed a metric on laws   in $\mathcal{P}_1$, we conclude that
$X$ and $S(X)$ have the same law, so the law of $X$ is in $\mathcal{P}$, whence $\mathcal{P}$ is closed in in $\mathcal{P}_1$.